# Doodlz App Location?

Tags: android

In the book that I'm using ("Android for Programmers, by the Deitels) the section of the first chapter devoted to introducing the AVD in full, has the user import an app called the 'Doodlz' app. I'm supposed to find it somewhere in the book's examples folder, but I've searched and searched and haven't found it. I'm not sure if this has to do with my not downloading something or if the book is slightly behind (i.e. changes were made to the SDK in the time following the book's publication) or what. Just needed a little help with this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this link, it allows registered users to download source code. But first see if your book came with a CD, or they usually list a URL to download the code.

http://www.deitel.com/Books/Android/AndroidforProgrammers/tabid/3606/Default.aspx